# WordPress not auto saving custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, autosave

I am custom post types in WordPress. I have also added several new input box other than the WordPress default ones. But the problem is WordPress is only auto-saving input box created by it and ignores all the fields created by me. When I refresh page all of them get cleared other than WP title box. So how can I add those fields to WP autosave too?

Comment: You want wordpress to save your custom post meta values during auto save?

Comment: @TBIInfotech Yes

Comment: This doesn't happen automatically. What have you tried yourself so far to achieve this? Have you looked into the save_post action hook? Please edit your answer with code you've tried yourself.

Comment: @engelen Actually I checked to form data submitted by WP autosave to the server. It doesn't send my custom fields to the server in the request

Comment: Please edit your answer with code you've tried yourself.

Comment: @engelen I don't know how to do it. So, I haven't tried any code. I tried searching for it but could not found something useful

Comment: Try following a few tutorials on this subject (the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) is a good place to start) and get back to us if you still can't figure it out.